# Req.body.objectName returning one undefined one defined value in node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, post

I am currently using express. When sending data from client side js to server in node.js, I am sending an object, but when trying to access that object in the server with req.body, req.body gives me two objects for some reason, one of them being empty, and the other being the right thing.
Im trying to figure out some way to get rid of that first object so I dont get req.body.element returning one undefined and one defined value.

client:

```
var abcd = {juice: "juice"}
  $.post( '/testing/this', abcd);
```

server:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started');
});

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/testing/this', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.body.juice)
  var dataToSendToClient = [{message:"potatohead"}, {message:"potatohead2"}];
  var JSONdata = JSON.stringify(dataToSendToClient);
  res.send(JSONdata);
});
```

When I run this, the line
`console.log(req.body)` 
logs {juice: 'juice'} AND {}

The line
`console.log(req.body.juice)`
logs juice AND undefined

because it somehow gets the data from the second empty object, which I don't know why it exists.

How do I get rid of that second bracket so logging req.body.juice only returns me juice?

[image: four things are logged even though I have 2 console.logs total]

Comment: No. one `console.log()` won't produce two outputs ... Are you absolutely sure there is only one request sent to the server? Change `console.log(req.body)` to `console.log("foo", req.body)` to be sure, the output you are seing is coming from this handler ... This is one of the seldom situation where a screenshot of the output would help to see the *exact*  output in your console

Comment: And why are you attaching two bodyparsers for JSON? Acually with a fairly recent version of exress, you don't need the `body-parser` package anymore. Express has `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded` built-in.

Comment: adding "foo" just added "foo" before each of those two objects(the empty and the full)

Comment: those are also the only 4 things in the console. at all, but ill keep that in mind for next time

Comment: Im not sure I have the most recent express, without the body-parser package it malfunctions sadly. Could that be related? maybe not having the newest express is causing this?

Comment: You can also try to define a global `let requestcount = 0` and then a `console.log("requestcount", ++requestcount)` as the *very first* statment in your request handler, to see if there are multiple requests arriving at the server

Comment: Yeah, the screenshot shows this output is not created during a single request, but there are two requests to that endpoint. One with the correct body, and one with an empty body.

Comment: Ohhhh that did it. You were right about two requests, I have no idea how I didn't spot this, thank you.